# Classifying multiple layers (vector or raster depending on what's easier) to one final layer distributing the different features weighted

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, rasterization, weighted-overlay

I'm using QGIS and currently I'm doing a Map Project and therefore I preselected every building that is available depending on the purpose. Then I wanted to do a second criteria which values which buildings fit the purpose of living better than others.

My criterias were:

- Building should not stand on a ground tilted more than 5 degrees,
- Building should not be further away than 50 metres from a parking lot,
- Building should not be further away than 400 meters from social activity places (e.g. bar, cafe etc.)

I got every building which got preselected intersected with the attributes, so now I have three layers (one for each secondary criteria) displaying which buildings meets the criteria of the layer. The layers are all vector layers but I could rasterize them if need be.

Now I want to classify which buildings are the "best" concerning the secondary criteria by weightening this criteria (e.g. Untilted ground is most important so its getting a factor *3, while social activities aren't that important so they are getting *0,5.)

As the final result I want to have one layer that displays every building that is preselected, and then categorized as e.g. good, average, or bad (concerning the secondary criteria). The problem about this is that I have no idea how to do this weightening of the secondary criterias. I tried rasterizing the vector layers and do something with the "ordered weighted averaging" file but I'm kind of clueless how this exactly works...